# Understanding fgetc in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, ida

i am working on a reverse engineering challenge(as a learning project), I am finding it difficult to understand what the block of codes below are supposed to do, Can please someone explain me with examples? Can someone tell that why is program comparing the return value of fgetc with 0FFFFFFFFH?

This is the fgetc which is used in program:

```
mov     eax, dword_12D33EC ; Read char from file
push    eax             ; File
call    ds:fgetc        ; Indirect Call Near Procedure
add     esp, 4          ; Remove push value from Stack of eax
mov     [ebp+var_10], eax
cmp     [ebp+var_10], 0FFFFFFFFh ; 
jnz     short loc_12D1202 ; Jump if Not Zero (ZF=0)
```

Other block(Please help me to understand how does the second instruction work?):

```
mov     ecx,0
mov     byte_12D3400[ecx], 32
jmp     short loc_12D11AF ; Jump
```

Declaration of byte_12D3400:
[Declaration of byte_12D3400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0QiQ.png)

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of `byte_12D3400` from the second snippet?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation of `fgetc`, especially at the section that says what the return value means?

Comment: Yes it says that fgetc returns an integer or EOF. I dont get that why is the code comparing it with this value(I may be confused so thats why asked for help).

Comment: Hi, added the declaration in the question

Comment: Uhm... It just checks for error?

Comment: why this specific value?

Comment: 0FFFFFFFFh  is -1 or EOF.

Comment: Oh thank you so much ,any idea about other query? I made the mistake of converting that hex number to decimal without caring for signed numbers.

Comment: It writes a byte into memory and jumps. Not sure what more can be said about that.

Comment: @interjay Just out of curiosity: in what assembly flavor is this syntax valid?

Comment: whats the meaning of byte_12D3400[0]. What happens when this goes to byte_12D3400[1] or [2]?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek It's intel syntax. @ Inderjit Chopra it will add the memory offset.

Comment: @interjay, Can you please explain me with an example? That would be very helpful

Comment: Hm in the Intel syntax I'm familiar with it's usually something like `mov byte ptr[byte_12D3400+ecx], 32`.